# How to restrict MDI area in Qmainwindow?

Tags: qt, toolbar, mdi

In Qt mainwindow, you may add toolbar and mdiarea. In that case, mdiarea is set as the central widget, which avoid overlap the toolbar.

Instead of a Qt toolbar, I have put a frame at top of the mainwindow, where normally occupied by toolbar or menu. Then I want to add MDI to the mainwindow. I found the MDI covers all the mainwindow area including my top frame and that is not what I want.

I want to make the MDI area such that it avoid the my top frame area just like treat the top frame as a real toolbar. Any suggestion about how to realize that?

Comment: if you want help you must provide a [mcve]

Comment: Have you tried simply putting a plain `QWidget` as central widget, then using `QVBoxLayout` to place both your top frame, then MDI window, inside that widget?